# The system environment check returned errors in typo3

Tags: environment-variables, typo3, internal-server-error, typo3-7.6.x, web-frontend

The system environment check returned errors. Those errors will affect the functionality and stability of your TYPO3 CMS instance. Please check the install tool "System environment" for all details.

The first image shows the typo3 backend status report error:

[image: **First image link** shows the typo3 backend status report error]

Here is the error on browser when I tried to access the frontend of the website:

[image: **Second image link** shows the error on browser when I tried to access the frontend of the website]
[image: **3rd image ** shows screenshot of php error log]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the actual error messages into your text? That way people can search for it. Also, the resolution of the images is really bad. I can barely read them.

Comment: The Exception in the frontend may be related but is probably not. **I would recommend to create a seperate question for that**. It's weird that you're getting an Exception in the core but without the entire stack trace it's not easy to determine what is causing it. More information could help. Is this a fresh installation? How did you set it up? Did you update previously?

Comment: Are you using the latest version 7.6.26?

Comment: Why are you using the tag **environment-variables**? Please consider: Using correct tags makes it easier for others to search for questions for a specific topic. Using more / unrelated tags will not make people more willing to answer your question (probably more the opposite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the exception you are getting: It seems you stumbled upon a [bug](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/commit/92b586c6c1c425013ebb01fc3de513fb458d2bb2) which is fixed in latest version [7.6.26](https://typo3.org/download/). Please update to the latest version. Make sure you follow the correct procedure for updating.

If the problem still occurs, clear the system cache in the install tool.

More general hints:

- Always keep your TYPO3 system up to date. Either subscribe to the [typo3-announce](http://lists.typo3.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/typo3-announce) mailing list or keep track of the channel `#announcements` in the typo3 slack workspace. That way you will be notified as soon as a new TYPO3 version is released. If you don't have access to the TYPO3 slack workspace yet, [register](https://forger.typo3.com/slack) for an invite.

Answer (score 0):

**first**:
go to Install-Tool and verify that all checks are green or at least yellow.

**then**:
if you only got a blank screen your system is probably in production mode where no error messages are shown as they could reveal information for abuse.
So configure **developer mode** in the Install-Tool.
You also may need to remove the exception handler in your typoscript (setup) with:

```
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
```

to get plain php error messages.

activating developermode :
[image]

1. Install Tool
2. Configuration Presets
3. Debug Settings
4. Debug
5. Activate settings

Comment: have you removed the errors from environment check in install tool? otherwise: show the specific error message from install tool (your screen shot just states "there are errors").

Comment: no error in install tool it shows only yellow and green test results

Comment: Can you help me please with httpd.conf file virtual host settings in xampp.....i mean to say RewriteCond and RewriteRule settings in httpd.con

Comment: that is another problem (or show the connection). open another question (not error-statement, see note to your question)

Comment: i did that sir.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382967/virtual-host-settings-for-typo3

Comment: why do you expect an error resolving by changes in the httpd.com file? why don't you do what I suggest?

Comment: system variable is fixed but browser showing same internal server error

Comment: please add the typoscript to the main template so you can get a debug stack with errorreport.

Comment: config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0....you mean to add this to typoscript...allready done this..... but still got no php error messages

Comment: and have you set your installation to develop mode?

Comment: i dont understand where i found the develop mode option in install tool...i have created the project allready...

Comment: I added a screenshot as tutorial to set developer mode

Comment: i added a screenshot of the result after turning on the developer mode

Comment: you should show more from the stack as with this only level no hints are given what and where the origin of the error is. **and insert an image and not a link.**

Comment: now we know that a query for session data breaks, but we still got no hints where this query is initiated. :(

Comment: I think we need the full stack. You might look yourself to identify an extension or something other which is responsible. Then you could deactivate that component, if possible. BTW: have you cleared all caches after changing important configuration (removing errors reported from install tool)?

Comment: yes i cleared all cache and i removed all the errors from install tool....can you give me your skype id for further talks about this :)

Comment: sorry, no resources for skype talks. you may try a slack channel.

Comment: And how do I connect to you slack i dont have your email :(

Comment: so I'm on slack too, I meant: get help from anyone else on [typo3.slack](https://typo3.slack.com) ([Invitation](https://forger.typo3.com/slack))