# virtual host settings for typo3

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, httpd.conf, typo3-7.6.x

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp_7/htdocs/BackupForEdow/Eddddddddd"
<Directory C:/xampp_7/htdocs/BackupForEdow/Eddddddddd>
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Is this correct for a typo3 project?

**I am not able to access the frontend of typo3** but my backend works correctly. The front-end shows an internal server error.

Please help me to create the virtual host.

Comment: You need to check the error log file.

Comment: '''''www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name '''' this error is shown in error log file...can you help me with this???

Comment: Be sure to include relevant information in your question. Not everyone reads the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vhost really does depend on other things: For example if you use the shipped .htaccess, you don't need the rewrite statements.

Copy the `_.htaccess` from the TYPO3 source to `.htaccess` in your document root for that.

About errors in general: As already recommended, look in the Apache (or php) error logs. Also look in the TYPO3 system log ("Log" in the Backend).

About the certificate error: You need to set up an SSL/TLS certificate if you want to be able to access your website via https://. *This is not a TYPO3 specific thing.* You may want to consult other resources, e.g. [search on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=server%20certificate%20does%20NOT%20include%20an%20ID%20which%20matches%20the%20server%20name).

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466086/enabling-the-openssl-in-xampp/11040496#11040496) helps.

Also, check if you can load your webpage via http://

For ssl in general you need these things:

1. Create a signed certificate. Your hoster should be able to help you with that. If you are setting up your TYPO3 installation on your desktop PC, you can skip that part for now and override the error message in the browser. For a public website you should always setup your certificates correctly, though.
2. Make sure the Apache ssl modules are enabled. I don't know enough about Xampp to help you there.
3. Create and enable a vhost file for ssl / port 443. Look for an existing example ssl vhost files in the sites-available directory, e.g. default-ssl.conf or search for examples online

Having a not correct server name in the certificate should usually not lead to a 500 error. It should generate a warning in the browser.